# Re-baking cookies?

Tags: cookies

I have just made a batch of peanut butter cookies using a recipe based on shortbread.

I have left them to cool and they are still slightly doughy in the centre.

I'm not sure if the peanut butter causes the doughyness, or if they just aren't cooked. Is it OK to put them back in the oven to cook them until hard throughout, or should i just leave them as they are?

Answer (score 2):

Peanut butter cookies should have a soft center. It's hard to say if you are overblowing a perfectly nice soft center by calling it "doughy" or not.

Some folks like authoritative sources to support such a wild claim. So, ATK said, in small part "achieve a crispier edge and a softer center." when justifying their choice of peanut butter here. https://www.americastestkitchen.com/recipes/853-big-super-nutty-peanut-butter-cookies

Of course, if YOU don't like them, sure, feel free to cook them more. But it is the way they "should" be per the "standard" (such as there is any) peanut butter cookie.

Answer (score -1):

Although it's tough to say without knowing the recipe, it is safe to say that they are not done baking. The cookies will probably end up a bit dry but it should be ok to cook them some more. However be careful that you didn't let the uncooked ingredients sit out too long (food poisoning) if they contain ingredients that will spoil.